# world to local coordinates

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, game-physics

I'm using ray picking and have now the coordinates in the World Matrix. How can I convert that to my Objects local coordinates?

Maybe convert the objects local coordinates to world coordinates.

Comment: Multiplying by inverse sounds like an idea, no? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. You say you use ray picking, which I read/understand as you select the position of a pixel in an image and compute from the point screen space coordinates the world point coordinates, where finally you want to get this point in object space coordinates?

Generally most 3D objects are applied a 4x4 matrix transform to be transformed in space (scaled, rotated, moved). When you object does not have this transformed applied to it, it is said to be in bind pose, or object space. When the matrix M is applied to the object, the resulting transformed object, is said to be in world space. If you have the matrix M (you know the matrix used to transform the object from object to world space) and that you have been able to pick a point on the object in world space (for example one of its vertices) and want to know what is the position of that point in object space, then all you need to do is applied the matrix inverse M-1 to this point coordinates (where M again is the matrix to go from object to world space).

Technically to get that working you need to find out:

- what is the object-to-world matrix applied to your object, do you know it, do you have access to this? Lets call this matrix M,
- you need to compute the matrix inverse M-1 from this matrix M, do you know how to do that?
- once you have M-1, then just do a simple point-matrix multiplication: Pobject = Pworld * M-1.

If you are not familiar or comfortable yet with matrices and matrix transform, I strongly advice you to read www.scratchapixel.com, particularly the lesson on matrices (lesson 4).

Lesson on matrices: http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-4-geometry/

Lesson on computing the inverse of a matrix: http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/matrix-inverse-row-reduction/

Comment: I will have to find out the Matrix M, going from object to world space. How do you compute the inverse Matrix and use it how ?

Comment: You need to look at the website I pointed you to: http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-4-geometry/ and http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/matrix-inverse-row-reduction/

Comment: I've been reading it and will continue. On this page  http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-4-geometry/coordinate-systems/    they mention"Adding the values (3, 1) to the coordinates" Where and how do they get the values (3,1)?

Comment: Do you know what a [4x4] matrix is? Matrix coordinates M(3,1) for example means the coefficient of the matrix from the 3rd row, 1st column of the matrix. Point/Matrix multiplication is not complicated but not something than can be explained in just a few lines. There's many subtleties such as whether you use row or column major notation for vectors. It's all very well explained on the website and doesn't need to be re-explained here.

Comment: Looking at the image on the page I can see where the (3,1) comes from but my question is where did that other coordinate system come from. Feels like the forgot to mention some magical part somewhere

Comment: The sentence is "Adding the values (3, 1) to the coordinates (-1, 3) leads to the coordinate (2, 4)". They mean take a point in 2D which coordinates are (3, 1) add them to a point which coordinates are (-1,3) and you get a point which coordinates are (2, 4). It's just an example to show how adding up point coordinates work. They haven't forgotten anything.